# Putting variables in quotation marks

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to insert a variable into quotation marks, see below my specific example

```
a<-renderText({
  isolate({input$Stock})
})
b<-getSymbols("a",from=2010-01-01,to=2015-01-01,auto.assign =TRUE )
```

Where I would like the variable a in the getSymbols function

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Try adding some sample data and a desired output to get good answers. But if all you want to do is use your variable as a text input you can just drop the quotations: getSymbols(a, ...)

Comment: It looks like you are using shiny with `renderText` and `isolate`? In addition to sharing sample data to reproduce, please edit your question and provide additional code to help in understanding context of what you're trying to do.